# NodeJs Package.json Infinite Recursive Dependency

Tags: json, node.js, package.json

This is a question I have been pondering. Is it possible that a Node project may encounter a recursive and infinite package dependency? What I mean is the following.

Suppose that the main application has the package A listed in its dependency section of `Package.json`. In turn, suppose this package A depends on a package B. That is, `node_modules/A/Package.json` will contain B in the dependency section.

Now, suppose in a crazy combination of events that package B depends on another package C (C!= A), which, however, has A as its dependency. To clarify,

```
node_modules/A/node_modules/B/package.json - contains C as dependency
node_modules/A/node_modules/B/node_modules/C/package.json - contains A as dependency
```

My question is two-fold. First, is such situation even possible in practice? Secondly, how would it be resolved? It seems to me that `npm install` would send this app for an infinite loop of installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OP: Is it possible that a Node project may encounter a recursive and infinite package dependency?

No.

From the [documented algorithm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm), as the dependency tree is walked, "dependencies will be added as close to the top as is possible."

The example given on that page says that if you have a package A that depends on a package B and a package C, and package B also depends on package C, the dependency in package B will be resolved by the copy already installed for package A.

So, in your example, package C's dependency on A would be met by the main application's dependency on A. No need to go fetch it again.

Things get a little tricky, however, when you start encountering dependencies that have dependencies on different versions of dependencies already met. In fact, the [next section](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#limitations-of-npms-install-algorithm) on that page talks specifically about this:

> npm flat-out refuses to install any name@version that is already present anywhere in the tree of package folder ancestors

They did give this recursive dependency installation stuff [some thought](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1341).